# problem with COCOAPODS on macOS 14 for flutter

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, cocoapods, macos-sonoma

I have this situation:

I've update macOS to Sonoma, also install android studio, Xcode and flutter, but in flutter doctor command its say:

CocoaPods installed but not working. so I did a procedure that I saw on the internet

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

`rvm install ruby-2.6`

`rvm use ruby-2.6.6`

`rvm --default use 2.6.6`

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

I ran flutter doctor again, and now it gives me the error: CocoaPods not installed

can you help me!

thanks

Comment: Did you have try install `cocoapods` by homebrew?

Comment: yes, and it still sends me CocoaPods not installed

Comment: Are you able to run `pod --version` ?

Comment: yes, not installed :( I can't install